# Solve Bessel equation with order $\frac{1}{2}$ using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Bessel equation of index $n= \frac{1}{2}$

$x^2y''(x) +xy'(x)+(x^2-\frac{1}{4})y(x) = 0$ $, x>0$

$(i)$ Show that $y(x) = u(x)x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ solves the equation above if and only if $u$ satiesfies a familiar differential equation.

$(ii)$ Find the general solution for the Bessel equation valid when $x>0$

$(iii)$ What condition(s) must the arbitrary constants in $(ii)$ satisfy if the corresponding solution of the Bessel equation is to be bounded on $(0,\infty)$

I solved $(ii)$ and found the solutions to be $y_1(x) =x^{\frac{-1}{2}}sin(x)$ and $y_2(x) = a_0x^{\frac{-1}{2}}cos(x)+a_1x^{\frac{-1}{2}}sin(x)$, where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are arbitrary.

But I'm not sure how to approach $(i)$ and $(iii)$, can anyone help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Israel told, just substitute $y(x) = u(x) x^{-1/2}$ in the differential equation and simplify. You will arrive to a simple expression. This end point (i).

Once point (i) has been solved, solve the new differential equation for $u(x)$. The general solution is what you name y2. This end point (ii).

For (iii), look at each of the pieces which compose y2. You know that $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ are finite and bounded for all values of $x$ and that $x^{-1/2}$ is defined for ???. Is there any problem when $x$ approaches $0$ ?

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: For $(iii)$, $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ is defined everywhere except at 0, but it was already specified that $x>0$. The only option that I can think of is for $a_o$ and $a_1$ to be $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ to cancel out the $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$. Is that right?

Comment: @user59036.a0 and a1 are constants. You cannot change them by functions of the variable; if you do so, the differential equation is not solved anymore.

Comment: Then there wouldn't be any conditions that the arbitrary constants need to satisfy?

Comment: I totally agree if x is strictly larger than zero. If x=0 is included, then a0 should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

For (i), what do you get when you substitute $y(x) = u(x) x^{-1/2}$ in the differential equation?